# When does a Cassandra read repair block a query

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra's `nodetool netstats` amongst others outputs the following: The number of read repair operations since server restart that blocked a query.

In which scenarios can a read repair block a (read?) query? I thought read repairs are always run in the background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A foreground read repair occurs when there is a mismatch discovered while reading from the chosen targets. So e.g. if your RF is 3 and you read at CL.QUORUM then if the 2 chosen replicas disagree, a blocking read repair is done to ensure you get the latest value from the 2 replicas.